# How to properly resize SVG in Safari [Markup working fine in Chrome/Firefox]

Tags: html, css, svg

In the following svg symbol, I'm trying to resize it according to the screen size, it is working fine in Chrome and Firefox, however in Safari, the size and position seems to be always the same regardless of the screen size, what am I doing wrong here or what should I change?

```css
.c-btn-play {
   max-width:80%;
   height: 100%;
   transform: translateY(15%);
   -ms-transform: translateY(15%);
   -moz-transform: translateY(15%);
   -webkit-transform: translateY(15%);
   -o-transform: translateY(15%);
}

@include mq($from: tablet, $until: desktop) {
  .c-btn-play {
    float:right;
    height: 85%;
  }
}

@include mq($from: desktop, $until:wide) {
  .c-btn-play {
    height: 90%;
    float:right;
    margin-right:10%;
  }
}

@include mq($from:wide) {
  .c-btn-play {
    height:120%;
    float:right;
    margin-right:23%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Symbols-->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="display: none; " >
  <symbol id="video-play" viewbox="0 0 60 70" >
    <g>
      <path fill="none" stroke="#231f20" stroke-width="2" d="M30,7C17.32,7,7,17.32,7,30      c0,12.68,10.32,23,23,23c12.68,0,23-10.32,23-23C53,17.32,42.68,7,30,7z" class="stroke-bg"></path>
      <path fill="transparent" stroke="#231f20" stroke-width="2" d="M30,7C17.32,7,7,17.32,7,30      c0,12.68,10.32,23,23,23c12.68,0,23-10.32,23-23C53,17.32,42.68,7,30,7z" class="stroke"></path>
      <path fill="transparent" stroke="#231f20" stroke-width="2" d="M24.89,40.84c-0.37,0.22-0.83,0.23-1.2,0.02s-0.6-0.61-0.6-1.04V20.2c0-0.43,0.23-0.83,0.6-1.04      c0.37-0.21,0.83-0.21,1.2,0.02l16.35,9.81c0.36,0.21,0.58,0.6,0.58,1.02s-0.22,0.81-0.58,1.02L24.89,40.84z" class="play"></path>
    </g>
  </symbol>
</svg>

<div class='grid'>
          <svg class="c-btn-play"><use xlink:href="#video-play"></use></svg>
</div>
```